# Position:fixed and margin:0 auto not working in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, margin, fixed

I have coded a website in HTML and CSS.

In this website I have used both properties `margin: 0 auto` and `position:fixed` on several occasions.

The problem is that the website is correctly displayed in any modern browser except for IE 8+.

Another problem that I found is that there should not be a space between the header and the browser window. Again this only happens with IE.

This issues are usually related with the quirks mode of IE. However in this case I set the doctype correctly `<!DOCTYPE html>`

The link to the website so you can check this out is: [http://juancarlosoleacañizares.es/index.php?page=0](http://xn--juancarlosoleacaizares-zec.es)

I would prefer a solution without using JavaScript.

Comment: Your URL won't open in FF, even when removing the `n` with line.

Comment: Thanks, i have change the domain to its international form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are non space characters before your doctype. The doctype should be the very first thing in the document. Because of this IE thinks the meta tags and others head elements are inside your body.

You can see this if you open the Developer tools (F12) in IE9.

The [w3 validator](http://validator.w3.com) would have told you too. Apparently it is a byte order mark (BOM), which should be omitted.

It's a good thing to learn to use these tools. They're essential for debugging problems like this.

Comment: But how can i get rid of that BOM since i saved all the documents with the _notepad++_ as "UTF-8 without BOM" and it still appearing

Comment: Maybe it isn't a BOM, or it is an incorrect/corrupt BOM. That may be why Notepad++ doesn't remove it. Maybe you can remove it manually, or use another editor for this specific task. I use Notepad++ a lot too and I've not had this problem before.