# BOM before doctype due to PHP file management functions

Tags: php, html, file, internet-explorer, byte-order-mark

I have asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7422619/positionfixed-and-margin0-auto-not-working-in-ie) why [my page](http://xn--juancarlosoleacaizares-zec.es) was not working in IE. The answer was that i had a byte just before the doctype.

However, i check it and re-check it, there is no a white space before doctype, i saved the document as ANSI, as UTF-8 without BOM (all of the with notepad) and it does not go away.

But, i was able to collect some interesting data. My website uses for displaying the content templates. **If i select the header (where the problem is) and display it directly in IE, it works!**

So i think the bit is added when the files are read from php and displayed. 
PHP codes for displaying the content:

```
    function gettemplate ($templatename) {
        $filename = './templates/'. $templatename . ".tpl";
        return ReadFromFile($filename);
    }
```

The extension of the files is *.tpl* but it works exactly the same as if it was *.html* (i have checked it)

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I do a hexdump of your Page:

```
$ GET http://juancarlosoleacañizares.es/ | hd | head -n 1
00000000  ef bb bf ef bb bf 3c 21  44 4f 43 54 59 50 45 20  |......<!DOCTYPE |
```

I see two BOM-Markers (two times EF BB BF) which is unusual. Have you checked if the .php-files themselves have BOM-Markers?

Comment: Thank you so much, it was the php-file where the function was the one in UTF-8 with BOM.